# How to accept focus C# WPF UserControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls, focus

I'm trying to create a date edit UserControl, but using TextBlock rather than TextBox because I want a single input context rather than manage six possible foci.

How do I accept focus? I tried setting Focusable to TRUE but it appears not to be enough. What else do I have to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you need to set `KeyboardFocus` to the element

Example:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
       mc:Ignorable="d" 
       d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
       FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"
       FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=mytextBlock}">
    <Grid>
       <TextBox Name="mytextBlock" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Or in codeBehind:

```
FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, mytextblock);
Keyboard.Focus(mytextblock);
```

Comment: Now isn't that odd - you haven't answered the question I meant to ask, yet you have answered the question I did ask, with an answer I do need. Thanks. Hey sa_ddam have you ever run into a problem with a usercontrol that works fine at run-time but throws a null ref exception when you click it as a widget on a WPF window in the VS2012 designer?

Comment: Yes, I have run into many problems with the new VS2012 designer, Most of the time it throws random errors and the designer will not load and I have to close the xxxx.xaml and reopen to resolve. Hope they sort it out in SP1 as I remember similar issues with VS2010 before SP1 was release(not as bad as VS2012, but it happened). I guess thats why so many people use blend, but I don't like the xaml bloat blend adds to my code.